# Get the exact value off "To the power off" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, pow

If you want to return the base to the exponent's power, you could either use `Math.pow(base, exponent)` or `base ** exponent`.

This works for small numbers like `20 ** 5`, but if you want slightly bigger numbers, `20 ** 200` for example, you only get the first few numbers. Thus, in this case `1.6069380442589902e+260`. And if you want even bigger numbers, such as `20 ** 20000`, JavaScript returns `Infinity`.

I want to return the exact number instead of only the first 17s. I know this is possible in Python; but how can I do it in JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript does not have intrinsic support for large numbers. Depending on what you are trying to do, there may be better technologies to use.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: `20 ** 200` isn't a safe number in JavaScript. The question @Rajesh linked above goes into a bit more detail about what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such large numbers, JS native numbers won't be enough; you could use some "Big Number" library, like, for example:

- https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/
- http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html